# Fastapi WebSockets RuntimeError: Cannot call "receive" once a disconnect message has been received

Tags: python, websocket, error-handling, fastapi

while reworking [Fastapi WebSockets tutorial](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/websockets/) received error on websocket connection lost, because of web page close or reload.

```
RuntimeError: Cannot call "receive" once a disconnect message has been received.
```

it was not critical, nor crash server. but leaving it be does no feels wright.

how to handle this WebSocket error?

-

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

A way to handle this error notification was to add try / except RuntimeError

```
while True:
    try:
        msg = await websocket.receive()
    except RuntimeError:
        break
```

Comment: You are not handling the error. Actually, this is not a good practice, and you are hiding possible errors that raise RuntimeError.